# I am getting an error in python using flask and it is very hard to understand, is there something wrong with my code or the library?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using flask and python and I am making a website, **I have two files, a python file and an html file**.
I am also using Pycharm for this project.

**Python file**, "main.py"

```py
# Import and Setup
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


# Functions
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("template/index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**HTML file**, "index.html"

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```py
* Serving Flask app "Main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-08-08 16:45:36,119] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:/Users/tohar/PycharmProjects/Website/Main.py", line 10, in home
    return render_template("template/index.html")
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 115, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\tohar\PycharmProjects\Website\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template/index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2020 16:45:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

It is fine when I first run it, then when I open the site, the site says **Error 500, internal server error** and this error shows up in the terminal. **Im not sure if it is my code's problem or something else, how can i fix this?**

Sorry! I cannot embed images into my posts yet, [Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jaN.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and input the actual code rather than linking to it.

Comment: The file `template/index.html` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Do you see the error?

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template/index.html
```

You do not have a `template` directory.  So, try: `return render_template("index.html")`

Better yet, make a `templates` directory, and put the `index.html` file inside.  Flask will look inside the `templates` directory by default.